# Can I use the same Firebase project to get push notification for both android and iOS application?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have create a firebase console project for testing push notification service and use the json.plist file in an android project. Now I want to test it for iOS application. So can I use the same firebase console project for iOS push notification implementation or need to create different google firebase console project and plist file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the same Firebase Project when using FCM to both Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Just create a different app on the same project